# Nested Eager Loading count

Tags: laravel

I need to get the contacts count of each author

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

The following attempt doesn't work

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')
             ->whithCount('author.contacts')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, where you use a function to get the count.

```
Book::with(['author' => function($query){
   $query->withCount('contacts');
}])->get();
```

You can access likes count by `author->contracts_count;`